# How to control action when someone presses CLOSE BUTTON in installshield 2020 project?

Tags: installshield

How can i configure an action in installshield 2020 when someone presss the CLOSE WINDOW (X) button?

I am using Installshield 2020 R3 SP1 revenera

I can see the control for Cancel button BUT i cannot find something to control the CLOSE button. Lets say i want to reset a property when someone presses the CLOSE BUTTON (X), how do i do that?

Please suggest.

Comment: No inputs? its weird that no one has any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to User Interface > Dialogs > <Dialog_Name> > Behavior. Look for the cancel button and click on it. On the right side, click Plus symbol and add whatever you want to do and make sure to move your action to the top before the cancel events.

[image]

Comment: Not sure which version are you using but surely its not same as what i mentioned in OP

Comment: I am having IS 2020 as well but my answer was for Cancel button not the Close(X) button. I guess this is not possible atleast in basic MSI project